# c# CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE with HttpClient

Tags: c#, php, curl

I want to replicate the following code in C# with HttpClient. This is the php code which uses the same cookies as returned in the response

```
if($cookies) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,   dirname(__FILE__). '/cookies.txt');            
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  dirname(__FILE__). '/cookies.txt');
    }
```

What I have done so far is below

```
var returnedCookies = response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie").ToList();
```

and then use it as

```
string newCookie = string.Join(";",returnedCookies);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", newCookie);
```

I dont understand why this is not working, ive tried using `CookieContainer` as well but it doesnt work. Any help regarding this or is there any wrapper or library for `cURL` to use in `C#` Ill do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at LibCurlNet
https://github.com/pjquirk/libcurl.NET

It has some very good examples and you can actually send out a curl request with c#

```
public void sendCurlRequest(string url, bool post, string post_aata, bool cookies)
        {

        try
        {
            Curl.GlobalInit((int)CURLinitFlag.CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

            Easy easy = new Easy();
            Easy.WriteFunction wf = new Easy.WriteFunction(OnWriteData);
            string writingData = string.Empty;
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_URL, instagramUrl + url);


            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

            if (post)
            {
                easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                File.WriteAllText("D:\\cookies\\post_data.txt", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(post_aata));
                easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_aata);
            }

            if (cookies)
            {
                easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "\cookies.txt");
            }
            else
            {
                easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
            }
            var c = easy.Perform();
            int info = 0;
            CURLcode code = easy.GetInfo(CURLINFO.CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, ref info);
            easy.Cleanup();

            Curl.GlobalCleanup();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }


    }
```